# group string after keywords (at, after, until) ignore order

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to group any text after one of these keyword for

input: `/send 1 at 11:00pm for 3min`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, sendAt = 11:00pm, duration = 3min`

input: `/send 1 for 3min`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, duration = 3min`

input: `/send 1 at 11:00pm`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, sendAt = 11:00pm`

input: `/send 1 until 11:00pm`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, until = 11:00pm`

input: `/send 1 for 3min at 11:00 pm`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, sendAt = 11:00 pm, duration = 3min`

input: `/send 1 at 11am for 1 h`

desired result: `postNumber = 1, sendAt = 11am, duration = 1 h`

I've made the following regex but could'nt figure out how to make it agnostic to order of the keywords input

`(?<postNumber>\d+)(?: at (?<sendAt>.*))?(?: for (?<duration>.*))?(?: until (?<until>.*))?`

I tried to add positive lockahead but it matched all the digits in the first group
`(?<postNumber>\d+)(?=(?: at (?<timeToSend>.*)))?(?=(?: for (?<duration>.*)))?(?=(?: until (?<until>.*)))?`

Comment: This is simply not a regular expression problem.  Just break the command into words, and parse each word one at a time.  The first word of each clause (for, at, until) tells you what things to expect next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enclose each of the capture groups in a positive lookahead pattern so that they can be matched in any order:

```
\/send\s+(?<postNumber>\d+)(?=(?:.*\bat\s+(?<sendAt>\d+(?::\d+)?\s*\S+))?)(?=(?:.*\bfor\s+(?<duration>\d+\s*\S+))?)(?=(?:.*\buntil\s+(?<until>\d+(?::\d+)?\s*\S+))?)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ks5YHN/2